MSVC fails to specialize member of template class defined in a separate translation unit
I've been trying to compile VTK 9.3.1 as a static library with Visual Studio 17 2022, but it fails at the linking stage:
vtkCommonCore-9.3.lib(vtkSMPToolsAPI.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl vtk::detail::smp::vtkSMPToolsImpl<1>::IsParallelScope(void)" (?IsParallelScope@?$vtkSMPToolsImpl@$00@smp@detail@vtk@@QEAA_NXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl vtk::detail::smp::vtkSMPToolsAPI::IsParallelScope(void)" (?IsParallelScope@vtkSMPToolsAPI@smp@detail@vtk@@QEAA_NXZ)

(Note: as dynamic library it builds fine. )
I found that the issue had already been reported, e.g. here, yet it remains unsolved.
I simplified the problem down to the following standalone MRE (moved to the end of post for better readability).
When I set the standard to C++17, MinGW compiles the code just fine while MSVC fails with the same type of linking error:
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned __int64 __cdecl Brick<0>::GetNumberOfSides(void)" (?GetNumberOfSides@?$Brick@$0A@@@QEAA_KXZ) referenced in function main

It seems to me that for some reason the compiler fails to put the definition of Brick< ShapeType::Circle >::GetNumberOfSides into the object file Circle.obj, which is why the linker can not find it.
My question is: Is the minimal example (provided below) correct according to the C++17 standard?
In other words, is this a bug in the Microsoft compiler or is it MinGW (GCC) that is overly permissive?
Note: MSVC compiles the code correctly when set to the C++20 standard.
Brick.h:
#ifndef Brick_h
#define Brick_h

#include <cstddef>


enum class ShapeType
{
    Circle   = 0,
    Triangle = 3,
    Square   = 4
};


template< ShapeType Shape >
class Brick
{
public:
    std::size_t GetNumberOfSides() 
    { 
        return static_cast< std::size_t >( Shape );
    }
};

#endif // Brick_h

Circle.cxx:
#include "Brick.h"


template<>
std::size_t Brick< ShapeType::Circle >::GetNumberOfSides()
{
    throw 0;
}

main.cxx:
#include <iostream>

#include "Brick.h"


template<>
std::size_t Brick< ShapeType::Circle >::GetNumberOfSides();

int main()
{
    Brick< ShapeType::Circle > B;
    
    try
    {
        std::cout << B.GetNumberOfSides();
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        std::cerr << "Uncaught exception - terminating. ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.12...3.29 FATAL_ERROR )

project( Toy VERSION 1.0 )

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 )
set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True )

add_executable( Toy main.cxx Circle.cxx )

target_include_directories( Toy PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )

Building commands:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .


Can't reproduce. What are your compiler options (please edit the question accordingly)?

@Oersted I don't believe the specific options should matter as long as you use C++17, but I've added the build method.

hum... I checked with C++17. Btw add /permissive- as compiler option (it should be mandatory with msvc...) but It does not change the outcome on my side. By the way my compiler version is 19.40. What's yours?

@Oersted The minimal example builds correctly with the /permissive- option. The original question still stands, but this is already very helpful - thanks! My compiler is MSVC 19.41.34120.0.

It looks ill formed if the template isn't explicitly instantiated, because different instantiations of this function template can give different code depending on where it is instantiated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170 => without it all bets are off.

@AhmedAEK IMHO your right. Shouldn't it be extern template? (not sur if its legal on a single function but all my compilers accepted it)

@AhmedAEK oups "you're" not "your"; "sure" not "sur". Not enough sleep probably ;)

I don't follow - the template is explicitly instantiated on lines 6-7 of `main.cxx'.

That's not an instantiation, it's a declaration.  Since the function was already both declared and defined in Brick.h that shouldn't change anything.

@MarkRansom I withdrew my agreement with Ahmed AEK. Technically the program is well formed but shouldn't do what is expected (using the specialized implementation). Yet, I've just test on both msvc and gcc, and they both use the specialized version instead of the primary one. I don't get why.

MSVC also uses the specialized one if you add /permissive- so ... i wonder if something in the standard guarantees this or it is only how compilers agreed on doing to not break user code

My best guess is that your declaration in Main.cxx is hiding the one in the library.  Try removing it and see if it helps.

@MarkRansom removing the declaration from main.cxx makes the program build, but the general definition of Brick::GetNumberOfSides is used instead of the specialized one - this is not the desired behaviour.

It's not clear what you want to do here.  If you wanted to override the global definition of GetNumberOfSides you need to put an actual definition of the function in main.cxx.

P.S. I don't see any usage of a static library here, you're directly linking two object files.

@MarkRansom Yes, the desired behaviour is for the specialized definition to override the global definition. The distribution of code between files is not my idea, I copied the structure from VTK where the very same linking error occurs. I am not trying to change the code so that it works, in which case obviously I would put the definitions together. I am wondering if the code is correct as it stands and whether it produces the desired behaviour according to the standard, because this decides whether it is the VTK team of Microsoft who should fix their stuff. Also I'm just curious.

Maybe this is unclear: I am not trying to build a project linking to the VTK library. Rather, I have extracted a problem existing in the VTK library itself into a standalone project. In other words my project is an MRE of the linking error that VTK struggles with.

@Adayah the explicit specialization is declared prior to usage so program should build (and throw uncaught exception). It is MSVC that is documented needing that /permissive- option for standard compliance mode. But you might want to add language_lawyer tag to your question if you want someone to dig in C++ standard for precise answer.
